# Yellow mexican singer in system 7 / mac os 8?

Tags: classic-mac-os

What was that extension in System 7 and Mac OS 8 which put a little yellow smiley thing of a mexican singing out of tune on your screen?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Jared: the Butcher of Song

http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jared_Smith

Comment: Upvoted, though should have downvoted to discourage the remembrance of such a horrible bit of Mac trivia. ;-)